# Custom activities depends on activities from diferents pipelines in Azure Data Factory v2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a custom activity in a project of Azure Data Factory v1 with 2 input datasets, these datasets are output of activities on different pipeline. The custom activity waits for these 2 activities to start. I have other custom activity on other pipeline with similar situation, with a common input dataset.

I want to do the same functionality on Azure Data Factory 2. But the custom activities don't have input datasets.

I read about the activity ExcecutePipeline and I think put 2 of them on the pipeline of the custom activity which invoke the pipeline when dependency activity is in. But if I do the same on the two pipelines where the custom activities are, the pipeline with the common activity of input dataset in custom activities run twice.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [activity dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities#activity-dependency) in ADF v2.

And could you also elaborate a little bit more about your exact activity flow?

Comment: I read the link and I had read it before, but it didn't work for me. I want activity dependency in diferents pipeline, the doc explain how do it but in the same pipeline

Comment: Execute pipeline activity has a property named "waitOnComplete". I guess you could set it as true. And then use if activity to check the output of the execute pipeline activity.

Comment: Execute pipeline invokes another pipeline and I can invoke the same pipeline more than once if I use this activity on my created pipelines. For example, if I invoke the pipeline from his children and he has more than one then the pipeline run 1 time for each child, and something like that happen if I invoke the children on the father.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here [Azure data factory v2 activity depends on activities from more than pipeline](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5e9d066a-6cb8-4fd0-b3d9-ac9ff08117a3/azure-data-factory-v2-activity-depends-on-activities-from-more-than-pipeline?forum=AzureDataFactory#5e9d066a-6cb8-4fd0-b3d9-ac9ff08117a3). If I create a new pipeline and wrap the others pipeline here with the Execute Pipeline Activity and "waitOnComplete" activity, I can run the required logic.